# Retrieve list<string> from Firestore into flutter page

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to show the details as shown in image present in my Cloud Firestore to the show movie flutter page but don't know how to retrieve List from Firestore and in showing that in the custom card as implemented in the code.
I have tried other approaches but was not successful.
Can someone help to implement the above mentioned?
This is my first question on this so sorry for mistakes.

```
    class CustomCard extends StatelessWidget {
      CustomCard(
          {@required this.movie_name,
          this.genre,
          this.famous_cast,
          this.rating,
          this.comment,
          this.free_link});

      final movie_name;
      final genre;
      final famous_cast;
      final rating;
      final comment;
      final free_link;

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Card(
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0, horizontal: 10.0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(movie_name),
                Text(genre),
                Text(famous_cast),
                Text(rating),
                Text(comment),
                Text(free_link),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    class ShowPage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _ShowPageState createState() => _ShowPageState();
    }

    class _ShowPageState extends State<ShowPage> {
      final db = Firestore.instance.collection('Movies');

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Show Movies'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[900],
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          body: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: db.snapshots(),
              builder:
                  (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                  case ConnectionState.waiting:
                    return new Text('Loading.....');
                  default:
                    return new ListView(children: getExpenseItems(snapshot));
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        );
      }

      getExpenseItems(AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        return snapshot.data.documents
            .map(
              (doc) => new CustomCard(
                movie_name: new Text(doc["movie_n"]),
                genre: new Text(doc["genre"]),
                famous_cast: new Text(doc["famous_c"]),
                rating: new Text(doc["rating"].toString()),
                comment: new Text(doc["comments"]),
                free_link: new Text(doc["free_link"]),
              ),
            )
            .toList();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am not sure what `CustomCard` is expecting I assume it is a `List<Widget>` so you would want to do something like this.

```
class CustomCard extends StatelessWidget {
  CustomCard(
      {@required this.movie_name,
      this.genres,
      this.famous_casts,
      this.rating,
      this.comment,
      this.free_link});

  final movie_name;
  final List<Object> genres;
  final List<Object> famous_casts;
  final rating;
  final comment;
  final free_link;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Card(
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0, horizontal: 10.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(movie_name),
            ...genres
                .map(
                  (genre) => Text(genre + ', '),
                )
                .toList(),
            ...famous_casts
                .map(
                  (famous_cast) => Text(famous_cast + ', '),
                )
                .toList(),
            Text(rating),
            Text(comment),
            Text(free_link),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

getExpenseItems(AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        return snapshot.data.documents
            .map(
              (doc) =>  CustomCard(
                movie_name:  doc["movie_n"],
                genres:  doc["genre"],
                famous_casts:  doc["famous_c"],
                rating:  doc["rating"].toString(),
                comment: doc["comments"],
                free_link:  doc["free_link"],
              ),
            )
            .toList();
      }
```

Try This

Comment: I want to display the complete data in a card. I need help like how to pass that genre which is a List into my custom card and to put that into Text().

Comment: Can you tell me how can I pass that genre which you retrieved from the database to my custom card and how can I display that?

Comment: Try these changes

Comment: One doubt: What are those three dots int you edited code?

Comment: There's Error: 
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' in type cast.

Comment: the ... is a spread operator it takes a list and spreads out the elements of the list

Comment: yes I saw that try the changes I just made I made a couple

Comment: Thanks, It's Working Now. 
one thing: How can I show those list elements as comma separated?
sorry for the trouble.

Comment: I did that already but as my level is not that high to display my vote!